# UICollectionView Flicker When Reloading And Calling requestImageForAsset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, photos

I have a problem with a UICollectionView that I think I have narrowed down to the following area. The problem is that when I call a reload on the UICollectionView there is a flicker and 1 image is loaded followed by the correct image second. Almost like when you scroll new cells and it updates them but without any scrolling.

Now I've tested it with a plain

```
sampleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"LogoHome"];
```

And I get no flickering whatsoever so I've narrowed it down to the following code

```
[self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:[self.arrayPhotoAssets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                 targetSize:CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight)
                                contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                    options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary* info){

                                        UIImageView *sampleImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
                                        sampleImage.image = result;

                                    }];
```

which is inside of

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Is there any way that I can adjust the code to prevent the above happening? Here is the full snippet:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

////// GALLERY COLLECTION VIEW


if(collectionView.tag == 1){

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"galleryCell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    float imageWidth = 77;
    float imageHeight = 77;

    UIScreen *mainScreen = [UIScreen mainScreen];

    //NSLog(@"%f",mainScreen.bounds.size.width);

    // IPHONE 6

    if(mainScreen.bounds.size.width == 375){

        imageWidth = 92;
        imageHeight = 92;

    }

    // IPHONE 6 PLUS

    if(mainScreen.bounds.size.width == 414){

        imageWidth = 102;
        imageHeight = 102;

    }


    [self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:[self.arrayPhotoAssets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                 targetSize:CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight)
                                contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                    options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary* info){

                                        UIImageView *sampleImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
                                        sampleImage.image = result;

                                    }];

    return cell;

}


UICollectionViewCell *cell;

return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to set `sampleImage.image = nil`, before trying to call `requestImageForAsset`. This will clear your image view such that will remove flickering.

```
UIImageView *sampleImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
sampleImage.image = nil;

[self.imageManager requestImageForAsset:[self.arrayPhotoAssets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                 targetSize:CGSizeMake(imageWidth, imageHeight)
                                contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill
                                    options:nil resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary* info){

                                        sampleImage.image = result;
                             }];
```

Comment: Definitely improved it, slight flicker still there but it doesn't flick between 2 images anymore.

Comment: That flickering is because of delay, between setting imageview's image to nil, downloading new one, and assigning new image to imageview. If you want to avoid it, requestImageForAsset must cache downloaded images.

Comment: Thanks, is that not what "PHCachingImageManager" is for? I was looking at caching libraries and that is what i've done in previous versions but I thought I would use the above instead this time.

Answer (score 0):

Setting "isSynchronous" to true in the options passed to requestImage (PHImageRequestOptions) fixed the flickering for me.